# How to handle window scroll event inside a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I generally hate asking questions like this, but I am new to Angular and trying to wrap my head around all of the concepts. One aspect that is tricky to me is how different areas of the page interact with one another.

In my example, I have site whereby I need to add a particular classname to the body element when the page is scrolled X pixels. X being the height of a particular element.

In jQuery, it might look like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (top > ($('#header').height())) {
    $('body').addClass('scrolled');
  } else {
    $('body').removeClass('scrolled');
  }
});
```

In Angular, I'm not sure where to begin. A custom directive on the body tag? Does anyone have any suggestions or resources about this general type of problem I might look at?

Comment: Yup, such a directive would be a good starting point. If you haven't already, work through the Angular tutorial and see some videos on http://egghead.io in order to understand the basic workflow

Comment: I've been reading through an AngularJS book with good results. I haven't yet watched the videos but they are on the list! I have a good understanding of Angular's MVC approach, but I still feel like certain things haven't clicked in regards to element interaction for me just yet.

Comment: Personally, i like to think of directives as (mostly) autonomous 'gadgets'. Where jQuery goes and says, hey, there lies a news-widget, let#s grab it and paint it blue, Angular creates said widget and gives it its own tools to paint itself blue. All in one handy place.
http://builtwith.angularjs.org has some good examples of code.

Comment: @Sprottenwels Yes, that is how I am trying to think of it, as well! However, what I am not entirely certain of is the "Angular way" of communication between "widgets". In this case, Body's behavior depends on #header's height and the current window scroll position. In jQuery we are used to referencing other elements (by selector) but in Angular, what is the method that is recommended for this type of interaction?

Comment: I would use a shared service. Services are way to provide data (and methods to interact with it), which can be injected where ever they are needed. E.g, you could create a service, update a property each time the page is scrolled and set up a watcher in your directive for that value. Your directive will then be notified about each change of this property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a directive for such tasks is a perfect match. I've created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anzeo/3twMW/) to demonstrate how to use this.

The code of your directive can be as simple as this (no jQuery):

```
angular.module("app").directive("scroll", function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element[0].addEventListener("scroll",function (event) {
                var header = document.getElementById("header"),
                    body = document.getElementById("scrollMe");

                if (body.scrollTop > header.offsetHeight) {
                    body.classList.add("scrolled");
                } else {
                    body.classList.remove("scrolled");
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I suggest reading up on the Angular docs and watching the egghead tutorial videos. They are a great help when starting with Angular development.

Also, [this article](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/12/07/dont-fear-directives-in-angular-dot-js/) sums up nicely why you shouldn't be afraid of using directives.

Comment: So directly interacting with and referencing elements by ID, etc. is still the way to go then, we just package/invoke the code differently, ie in a directive in this case vs a global piece of jQuery code lying about?

Comment: Exactly. A directive should be viewed as an extension of HTML. So if you'd like some elements to have this scrolling functionality, make a directive for it and put it on any element you want. The directive in my example is not yet fully resuable ofcourse, but you can understand what I mean.